# Input length restriction in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

I programmed kakuro-solver, but I have problem with user's input. When user want to enter input longer then 1024 chars, haskell trims input and throws exception

```
<interactive>:9:1024:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

For example I want to enter this input

```
kakuro [(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,6),(-1,0,23),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,7),(-1,0,23),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,18),(-1,0,12),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,12),(-1,0,26),(-1,9,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,13,19),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,7,23),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,3,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,5,16),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,18,10),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,7,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,10,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,21,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,20,15),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,24,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,11,20),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,17),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,14,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,23),(-1,0,12),(-1,0,15),(-1,20,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,10,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,26,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,13),(-2,0,0),(-1,13,19),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,13,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,33,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,15,30),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,16),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,21),(-1,0,29),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,16,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,31,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,12),(-1,17,13),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,11),(-1,0,23),(-2,0,0),(-1,10,37),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,26,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,11),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,4,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,16,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,9),(-1,0,16),(-1,34,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,17,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,18,14),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,13),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,20),(-1,4,13),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,7),(-1,18,21),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,21,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,22,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,33,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,6,17),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,9,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,8,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,13,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,3,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,16,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,11,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,17,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0)]
```

but WinGHCi trims it to

```
kakuro [(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,6),(-1,0,23),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,7),(-1,0,23),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,18),(-1,0,12),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,12),(-1,0,26),(-1,9,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,13,19),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,7,23),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,3,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,5,16),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,18,10),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,7,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,10,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,21,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,20,15),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,24,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,11,20),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,17),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,14,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,23),(-1,0,12),(-1,0,15),(-1,20,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,10,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,26,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,0,13),(-2,0,0),(-1,13,19),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-1,13,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,33,0),(0,0,0)
```

I tried use monad, but there is the same problem, I have to split input to more lines.

Is there any options, how enter inputs longer then 1024 chars?

Comment: while AJFarmar's answer work I myself hate to do this in ghci - I would just put my input in a *.hs* file and load it (`:load myFile.hs`) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
λ> :{
|  let result =
|       kakuro [
|    (-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),
|    (-2,0,0),(-2,0,0),(-1,0,6),(-1,0,23) ...
|      -- AND SO ON...
|              ]
| :}
```

And then just evaluate `result`.

However, I imagine that you've taken the list from the result of a previous command. In GHCi, the result of the previous expression is `it`, so you could probably write `kakuro it`. If you haven't done that, then read it from a file:

```
λ> kakurodata <- read `fmap` readFile "/file/data/here.txt"
λ> kakuro kakurodata
```

EDIT: @Carsten pointed out that you could just plonk it in a file and `:load` it. Thanks!

Comment: I always like to point out that with `:set +m`, you have multi-line input in GHCi.  I keep this in my .ghci settings file.  This avoids needing to use the `:{ :}` wrapper, although it's still available for use.